# Google Sheets Formula Vlookup issues

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good Morning,

Right now we  have a field where we are using =vlookup to find data matching certain identifiers.This data come from sheet "Raw Data" and is filtered into "Data".

Now what I want to do is be able to fill in extra data in B2:F5 in columns which are empty without the formula breaking / being removed or getting an #REF.

The vlookup I am using right now

```
=arrayformula(transpose(VLOOKUP(A2;'Raw Data'!A2:F5;{2;3;4})))
```

Example file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17M5muIZA2nUgjRTj_OHlW9Fw6IECEFWuYuYmgFh3lEM/edit#gid=0

Comment: It seems your formula giving your correct output. What is issue with your current formula?

Comment: I would like to add manual data in empty columns in "Data" sheet. Without removing the vlookup formula or override it or give it an #REF

Comment: You cannot do what you are trying to do. Your formula "owns" the range you're telling it to send output to, and any cell can *either* be reserved for formula use *or* open to manual entry—not both. The only way, then, to achieve what you want to do is to have scripts do calculations and value writing in cells, which would remove live formulas and allow you to enter data in that range manually. Another option is to enter the manual data into the "Raw Data" sheet directly (or into an additional sheet and then modify the formula, which is do-able but complicated).

Comment: I was thinking to have a dynamic index in the vlookup. So right now its indexing 2,3 & 4. But would it be possible to check which are filled and then only index those? @ErikTyler

Comment: Your overall real-world goal is still not clear to me. But as I and player0 have pointed out, you can either have a cell's value determined by formula or open for manual entry, not both. Maybe if you explain your full real-world goal, you'll reveal something we aren't seeing now. But based only on the small data sample and setup you have shown, it is not possible without script or entering your manual data into the second sheet instead of the first.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; 'Raw Data'!A2:F; {2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6}; 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula doesn't achieve what I had in mind. I need in your picture D2:F2 to be editable without the formula breaking.

Comment: @Scraper2022 that is not possible. the best you can do is to have 1 formula in each cell but still, if you want to fill the cell you will lose the formula